# Trouble understanding foreach (x =>) syntax

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, foreach

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to understand another developer's code - see below:

```
        nameFile.ForEach(x =>
        {
            FileChecker singleFile = new FileChecker();
            singleFile.FileName = x;
            singleFile.FoundDT = DateTime.Now;

            singleFile.IsData = this.IsData(singleFile.FileName);
            singleFile.IsStore = this.IsStore(singleFile.FileName);
            if (singleFile.IsData )
            {
                //...               
            }
        });
```

And here's a snippet of code from `FileChecker`'s definition:

```
public FileChecker()
{
    this.fileDownloaded = false;
    this.IsData = false;
    this.IsStor = false;
}
public bool IsData { get; set; }
public bool IsStore { get; set; }
```

I have two questions:

1. Can someone explain or point me to a link that explains how this foreach works? ForEach(x=>...);
2. I don't understand how this statement`(singleFile.IsData )` works, since the definition is only: `public bool IsData { get; set; }`
   In other words, what was the developer trying to look for? What does IsData mean? Was he intending to see if it matched a criteria (like filename syntax)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question is answered above, its just a lambda expression which carries code that needs to be executed on each iteration of foreach.

For the second question, if you are looking for the purpose of IsData property go inside the IsData method in that class(class in first code block).

Comment: Thanks for helping with the 2nd question! @gordanvij

Answer (score 4):

It is the same as

```
foreach (var x in nameFile)
{
...
}
```

`IsData` is an automatic property.  Look it up...

Answer (score 2):

1. [List.ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) accept a delegate which will be executed for each item in the list, in your case code block after the `=>` would be executed for each item in the `nameFile` list, and `x` would be an item variable.
2. This is automatic property definition, backing field would be generated under the hood for you this is why you can use it without defining a field manually

You might find useful article: [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

1. See this intro article on lambda expressions:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
2. `public bool IsData { get; set; }` is a shorthand property declaration, which is similar to writing:

   ```
   private bool _isData;
   public bool IsData 
   { 
      get {return _isData;}
      set {_isData = value;}
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

1. The x=> ... is called a [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) expression.
   It just says "for every element, name it 'x' and pass it to the following code".
2. Was explained enough, only worth pointing out that while this is much shorter to write, you need to set default parameters in the constructor instead of directly on the member field, because you don't have one. And you can even use this automated properties with a private setter.

Answer (score 1):

[ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), and part of System.Linq (edit:  [there is one in List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) which takes an Action, but System.Linq has additional extensions).  It operates on List.  The x=> bit is part of a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  IsData is just a boolean value exposed as an [auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) ... it can be true or false.